# How to adjust space between items along the main axis in a flex cotainer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]I am trying to decrease the margin between the (header__title-title) and the first item (header__title-symbol) in the flex container. I can't seem to get anything to work. Any suggestions? The main axis is vertical since I have the flex-direction set to column

```
<div class="header__title">
        <div class="header__title-symbol">
          <span class="span-one"><hr id="hr-one" /></span>
          <span id="symbol">&#11033;</span>
          <span class="span-two"><hr id="hr-two" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="header__title-title">
          <h1>The Website title!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>


.header__title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}


.header__title-title {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-shadow: 0 4px 4px #d19224;
  animation-name: moveInLeft;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  font-family: "Zen Kaku Gothic Antique", sans-serif;
}

.header__title-symbol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

hr {
  width: 27rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.3rem;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: In Chrome, the margin-block attribute is automatically added to the h1 tag. See if adding "h1 {margin-block: 0}" in your css fixes your problem.

Comment: Please see the picture I added. I am trying to decrease the margin between the website title and the lines above. Your solution did not work @JuanManuelLópezManzano

Comment: Hi Tim, maybe you could decrease the line-height

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem **does not** related to CSS flex property. you could add these lines in your CSS file:

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This code resets the margin and padding of all elements in your **html** file. Then you can set each amount of margin or padding that you want to the `.header__title-title` class that is suitable for your design. for example:

```css
.header__title-title {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways by which you can achieve this.

1. Add a `margin-top` or `margin-bottom;` to the ones you want to add space.
2. When you add display: flex and flex-direction: column, then by using `justify-content: space-between;`

Hope this works for you.